# Different Pivot field selection with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to update the pivot with VBA, However my below code is not getting updated once the first criteria is Hidden rest is not getting hidden automatically, I am lost with this. Any support will be highly helpful, attached is screenshot post code execution.

```
Sub Pivotselection()

Sheets("Daily Facing Service by WH").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Ordtype").Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("TOTLNS").Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("TOTFCA").Orientation = xlHidden

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WH")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("Monthly Facing Service").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Ordtype").Orientation = xlHidden
Sheets("Calculations").Select
Range("E8").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've named them incorrectly. As they have been added to the value field already there name has changed so you need to reference them with their new name

```
Sub Pivotselection()

Sheets("Daily Facing Service by WH").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of Ordtype").Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of TOTLNS").Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of TOTFCA").Orientation = xlHidden

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WH")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("Monthly Facing Service").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Ordtype").Orientation = xlHidden
Sheets("Calculations").Select
Range("E8").Select
End Sub
```

Also I'd get rid of your `.Select` statements. They don't seem to be doing anything